# How to create a video sequence made up of random frames in Final Cut Pro 7?

Tags: video

I am editing a music video in Final Cut Pro 7.
I would like to create a random frame sequence, a flashing-frame effect to insert into the video.

Any ideas on how to create it?

Comment: frame by frame manually

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiar with FCP7 but it should approximately work like this: Collect random frames in a folder, name them in the order you want them to appear (frame001, frame002, etc.) and import those images into FCP. The naming can be done with [software](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33659/rename). [Here's](http://www.dvxuser.com/V6/showthread.php?200913-Making-a-Timelapse-in-FCP) a forum post explaining it. I will leave it to someone who has used FCP to write an actual answer.

Comment: are these frames images from elsewhere like photos, stills, artwork etc ? or have you exported each frame of the videos ?